# Given return address, how to get the address of the function?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Suppose in a piece of C code, I have a function **foo** that calls **bar**. While inside **bar**, I can use assembly to get the address to which **bar** will return to. How do I use this information to determine the address of **foo**?

One approach would be to obtain the return address that **foo** will return to, and get the address from the opcode of the **call** instruction that calls **foo**. However, this requires knowing which calling method (e.g. offset/absolute) is used, therefore unreliable. Is there an easier way to do determine the address of the caller?

edit: I forgot to mention that this question is about IA32 assembly on 32-bit Intel unix machines.

Comment: Since this question involves assembly code, perhaps you can tell us what assembly language we're targeting?

Comment: This will be processor dependent.  There won't be a generic way to do this successfully.

Comment: @StevenBurnap, don't you mean architecture dependent?

Comment: @user2467539 is it not sufficient enough to use `&test_func`? the problem you pose is challenging, since there may be more than one return instruction within a single function. I guess I'm just curious if this is a practical matter or an educational one.

Comment: @TaylorFlores the problem is I don't know the name of foo when doing this, therefore cannot use such notations. Although not a homework problem, I guess it's more of an educational matter, since in practice we usually know all the functions we are using.

Comment: okay. if it's a c-compiled program, how about back-tracing to a `push ebp` instruction within the function?

Comment: I agree this is a better way to do it. However, what makes me feel uneasy is that this relies on the assumption that the function starts with `push ebp`, and does not contain any `push ebp`'s in the function body. I'm not very familiar with the compilation details, but does this assumption always hold?

Comment: yeah, use `gcc filename -S` and you can take a look. it's the standard way compilation occurs on x86 architecture. But parsing cpu instructions is non-trivial, there's more within a single instruction than what is written in assembly. Take a look here http://penberg.blogspot.com/2010/04/short-introduction-to-x86-instruction.html and it may help you

Comment: and just to add, if you found another `push ebp` for some reason, you would also have found a `pop ebp` preceding the back-trace. so, implement a counter if you'd like to be extra sure. You can count on there being a corresponding `pop ebp` if there was a `push ebp` within the function body because otherwise the program would cause a stack corruption.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, you can use `dladdr()` to resolve the calling function, by using:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

...

void *retAddr = __builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0));
Dl_info d;
(void)dladdr(retAddr, &d);
printf("%s called from %s + 0x%p\n",
    __FUNC__,
    d.dli_sname,
    (retAddr - d.dli_saddr));
```

See [GCC docs, `__builtin_return_address()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) and Linux manpage [`dladdr(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) for details.

The function `dladdr()` is available on Solaris/MacOSX/*BSD as well but needs other preprocessor defines than `_GNU_SOURCE` to become visible; see the manpages for the respective operating system(s) ...

**Edit:** Note that since this relies on the presence of a symbol table, it might *not* resolve successfully on stripped binaries. I've not tried to add error handling to the above; in general, any type of automatic backtracing (with function name resolution) support doesn't like symbol tables being stripped off.

For a really quick one, I sometimes simply use:

```
#include <execinfo.h>

...

void *retAddr[10];
backtrace_symbols_fd(retAddr, backtrace(retaddr, 10), STDERR_FILENO);
```

as that gets a ten-entry deep stacktrace. Again, reliant on not having symtabs stripped off. There's a performance penalty for this as you're resolving more than a single addr.

**Edit2:** *Without* symbol tables (which, amongst other things, contain *start address* and *size* for functions within the executable/library), the information what's a "start address" is rather meaningless; as far as the CPU itself is concerned, there's not really any record kept of how the instruction pointer arrived at the place it is at a specific moment - the assembly-equivalent of `goto` (`jmp`) or other strange concoctions of self-modifying instructions are just as "valid" to the CPU as is properly-structured, compiler-generated code. x86 instructions are *variable size*, and the opcode map is *dense* enough so that just about any random sequence of bytes makes up a "valid" instruction stream; heuristic backwards-disassembling of binary code is therefore not a 100% safe thing to do.

Symbol tables, in that sense, establish "markers" for debuggers as well. You can be expected to find a valid instruction stream if you start disassembling at function start addresses as recorded in the symbol table, and can cross-verify that by validating that any return addresses found in backtraces are actually preceded by a `call` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

> One approach would be to obtain the return address that foo will return to, and get the address from the opcode of the call instruction that calls foo.

Eh? That will give you the address of *bar*, not *foo.*

All you need is the highest procedure entry point that is lower than the return address.

Comment: The "return address" here mean the address that foo will return to after finishing execution (which would be inside the function that calls foo).

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the "highest procedure entry point" is, and how we can find it?

Comment: (1) I know what a return address is, thanks. (2) The contents of the calling opcode have nothing todo with the address of the procedure that contains it. (3) The calling procedure has an entry point that is less than the return address. You just have to find the procedure whose entry point is closest to but less than the return address.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming regular page frames are present and that `bar` was called with a regular call (as opposed to a register-indirect one) to get the address of `bar` you go "out" one level further and find the `call bar` instruction.

While in `foo` your stack will look something like:

```
.
.
parameters to bar (if any)
return address, i.e. address following 'call bar'
saved base page (ebp register) value
locals to bar
...
parameters to foo (if any)
return address, i.e. address following 'call foo' within bar
saved base page (ebp register) value
locals to foo
```

So to get the address of `bar` from within `foo`, you would do something like the following (this is off the top of my head, so minor adjustments might be needed, but you should get the general idea).

```
mov eax, [ebp]   // load calling scope (bar's) frame pointer
mov eax, [eax+4] // load the return address for bar
mov edx, [eax-4] // load offset from the call instruction that called bar
lea eax, eax+edx // adjust (or something similar) to convert from offset to abs
```